# Angular tracking files upload progress reaches 100% before the upload is complete

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a service that uploads a list of files to a backend server.

```
createFiles(formData: any, userToken: string): Observable<any> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + userToken});
    const filesUrl = this.constants.HOST_URL + 'files';
    return this.http.post(
        filesUrl, formData,
        {
            headers: headers,
            reportProgress: true,
            observe: 'events'
        }
    )
    .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError)
    );
}
```

The service is consumed on a component like this.

```
export interface Upload {
    content: any | null;
    progress: number;
    state: 'PENDING' | 'IN_PROGRESS' | 'DONE';
} 

upload: Upload;

constructor( private fileService: FileService,) {}

this.fileService.createFiles(this.formData, this.token)
    .subscribe(
        (event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
            switch (event.type) {
                case HttpEventType.Sent:
                    this.upload = {content: null, progress: 0, state: 'PENDING'};
                    break;
                case HttpEventType.UploadProgress:
                    this.upload = {
                        content: null,
                        progress: Math.round((event.loaded / event.total) * 100),
                        state: 'IN_PROGRESS'
                    };
                    console.log(this.upload.progress);
                    break;
                case HttpEventType.Response:
                    this.upload = {
                        content: event.body,
                        progress: 100,
                        state: 'DONE'
                    };
                    console.log(this.upload.state);
                    break;
                default:
                    this.upload = {
                        content: null,
                        progress: 0,
                        state: 'PENDING'
                    };
            }
            if (this.upload.state === 'DONE') {
                this.files = this.upload.content;
            }
        }, error => {
            this.errorMessage = <any>error;
            console.log(this.errorMessage);
        }
    );
}
```

There is this progress bar that shows the upload progress on the component's template:

```
<mat-progress-bar [mode]="upload?.state == 'PENDING' ? 'buffer' : 'determinate'"
    [value]="upload?.progress">
</mat-progress-bar>
```

The problem is that, when uploading large files the progress bar moves from 0 to 100 in a few seconds then stays on 100 for a long period before it is updated to `DONE` status.

As shown on the screenshot below, the timestamps on the logs show there is a prolonged delay between the last `UploadProgress` event and the `Response` event logged by the `DONE` state of the Upload object.

[image: the log of the upload progress]
I have followed the example on angular's official guides but I'm still stuck on how to make the progress correspond with the status of the actual upload.

Comment: check if its going in httptype.response case before upload is complete.

Comment: @AakashGarg it is still on `HttpEventType.UploadProgress` but the progress is on 100% for most part of this event type.

Comment: do one thing console log your upload object in subscribe.

Comment: It still exhibits the same behavior. the logged upload object's progress increases fast from 0 to 100, then stays at 100 for a long time while the state is still `IN_PROGRESS` and then it's state changes to 'DONE' when it receives a response.

Comment: how is your upload object priting? can we have a screenshot?

Comment: I have updated the question with logged upload and the timestamps showing the delay between the last `UploadProgress` and `Response` events

Comment: Why your console didn't print Upload done?

Comment: Sorry about that I removed that log when I added the log in `HttpEventType.Response` case. I have updated the question with that correction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found where the problem was. I forgot that this was a dev environment and the files were being uploaded to a local server which was then saving the files to a remote storage service before returning a response. The fast 0-100% progress is the service uploading the files to the local server. The delay after the upload has reached 100% was the time taken by the local dev backend server to save the files to the remote service. The code works fine. I'm voting to close this question as a duplicate since there are other questions with answers on how to track `FormData` upload progress.